# How to get route param in cousin component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This question is about [React router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web).

Here's my App component:

```
export default function() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
            <Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
                <ScrollToTop>
                <Grid>
                    <TopBar>
                        ...
                    </TopBar>
                    <SideBar>
                        <SideBarHeader>Classes</SideBarHeader>
                        <ClassList/>
                    </SideBar>
                    <Main>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/class/:id" component={ClassDoc}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Main>
                    <Footer>
                        ...
                    </Footer>
                </Grid>
                </ScrollToTop>
            </Router>
        </ApolloProvider>
    )
}
```

The `<Main>` content is rendering correctly. However, in my `<ClassList/>` I want to gain access to the "class id" (same as used in the `<Route>` below).

I don't want to do

```
<Route path="/class/:id" component={ClassList}/>
```

Because I want to render the `ClassList` unconditionally, whether or not that path matches. If there's an `id` available I just want to highlight something.

I tried using `withRouter` but it's giving me

```
{path: "/", url: "/", params: {}, isExact: false}
```

instead of the /class route. i.e. the root route which is missing the params.

So how do I get the class id to `ClassList`?

---

For the time being, I've copied the `Switch` twice, but this isn't going to be good for maintainability.

```
<SideBar>
    <SideBarHeader>Classes</SideBarHeader>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/class/:classId(\d+)::releaseId(\d+)" render={({match:{params}}) => <ClassList {...params}/>}/>
        <Route path="/class/:classId(\d+)" render={({match:{params}}) => <ClassList {...params}/>}/>
        <Route component={ClassList}/>
    </Switch>
</SideBar>
<Main>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/class/:classId(\d+)::releaseId(\d+)" render={({match:{params}}) => <ClassDoc {...params}/>}/>
        <Route path="/class/:classId(\d+)" render={({match:{params}}) => <ClassDoc {...params}/>}/>
    </Switch>
</Main>
```

Answer (score 0):

So `withRouter` should work (or `<Route>{()=>}</Router>`, see: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func)

Do you have a `shouldComponentUpdate` or redux `connect` in your sidebar? This can be blocking the `withRouter` update.

Comment: Neither. `withRouter` is giving my component *something* but not what I want. How would it even know which route to feed me? `ClassList` is earlier in the JSX than my `Route`s too so it can't even do some kind of stateful last-thing-matched hackery.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, you're current solution is a way to go, if you're using redux, a connectedrouter can be considered. Or a callback prop to the child component (from Grid to ClassList and to ClassDoc).